# Socket.io 'WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.'

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to build real time chat application with PHP and socket.io. I have problem with making connection to node.js side.

index.php

```
<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>

var serverLocation = "http://sub.domain.com:3000";

var socket = io(serverLocation);
```

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mysql = require('mysql');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Server listening at port %d", port);
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
 console.log('test)
})
```

When i try to use app, it returns this error.

```
GET http://sub.domain.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mkq7S0V net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I tried to change my connection method like this.

```
var socket = io(serverLocation, {
        transports: ['websocket','polling'],
        forceNew: true
    });
```

Then new error appears.

```
index.js:83 WebSocket connection to 'ws://sub.domain.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Comment: Is `process.env.PORT` set? Are you maybe not in fact on port 3000?

Comment: what is the output of `console.log("Server listening at port %d", port);`?